# Outputting Japanese Characters to a File

Tags: java, encoding, io, filewriter

How do i print the Japanese Characters in a file using `fileWriter` so that it does not appear as '???' question marks.

Whenever i am executing the program it prints the question marks, and when i change the font and language to MS Gothic and Japanese respectively, it does not make any change.

I have another file with Japanese Characters but when i open that it contains some Garbage looking Characters and not question mark. And when i change the font and Language like in previous case, it shows the Japanese characters just fine.

So my question would be how do i get 'Garbage charcters' on my file instead of the `???` so that when i change my font/language settings i get the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do i print the Japanese Characters in a file using fileWriter so that it does not appear as '???' question marks.

Don't use `FileWriter` to start with. That *always* uses the default encoding, which is probably not what you want.

Instead, use `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter`, which will let you specify the encoding - "UTF-8" is usually a good choice, so long as whatever's going to read the data will accept that. (It's not clear from your question what *is* reading the file - and it's very important to understand that both the writing code and the reading code need to *agree* on the encoding.)

Comment: @Kraken: It's not really appropriate to add comments to answers just to get attention to another (unrelated) question.

Comment: sorry, i thought it was on the similar lines and that you'd be able to help. Thanks though. :)